# SQL Query to get list of all users of type 1, plus a new column that tells if they also have type 2

Tags: mysql

I have a joint table that contains the id of users and their type. I need to be able to get the list of user ids with type 1, and a new column that tells if they have a type 2. (There's also a user table that I will have to join with the user_id.)

user_user_types joint table:

```
user_id     user_type
---         ---
100         1
100         2
200         1
350         1
350         2
400         3
```

The resulting table I want: (this is without the join)

```
user_id     has_type_2
---         ---
100         1
200         0
350         1
```

My query looks like this but currently only gets those with type 1, I'm not sure yet how I can add a new column that indicates if they have type=2 as well.

```
SELECT user_type, user_id, u.*
FROM user_user_types ut
WHERE user_type=1
JOIN users u ON ut.user_id=u.id
```

What's a good query for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a LEFT-join to the same table but including the type 2 condition...

```
SELECT 
      ut.user_type, 
      ut.user_id, 
      u.*,
      case when ut2.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end as HasType2
   FROM 
      user_user_types ut
         JOIN users u 
            ON ut.user_id = u.id
         LEFT JOIN user_user_types ut2
            ON ut.user_id = ut2.user_id
           AND ut2.user_type = 2
   WHERE 
      ut.user_type = 1
```

The original query WHERE qualifies your condition of user type = 1 first...  From that, a LEFT-JOIN to the user types table but by the same user ID, but ALSO qualifying the second table (ut2) also is user type 2.  By left-join, if no qualifying record, the ut2's user id column will be null indicating there is no match by its JOIN ON condition (which includes the type=2).

Comment: @Alphonsus, you are welcome... don't forget to review Help -> Tour for site etiquette.  Helps others know a question is solved and what worked (or not) from your question, in case others run into similar examples for their apps.